# How to read from database which stocks have been bought but not yet sold?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table (`portfolio`). It is a transaction log for a stock-market investor. Each day, he either `buy`s, `sell`s or `hold`s (previously bought stocks which are not yet being sold) stocks (identified by `sp100_id`):

```
_date       sp100_id  action  price
-----------------------------------
2011-03-21  11        buy     10.50
2011-03-21  55        buy     60.00
2011-03-21  99        buy      5.15
2011-03-22  11        sell     9.80
2011-03-22  55        sell    61.50
2011-03-22  99        hold     5.60
2011-03-23   1        buy     95.00
2011-03-23   2        buy     25.60
2011-03-23  99        hold
2011-03-24   1        sell    96.00
2011-03-24   2        hold
2011-03-24  99        hold
2011-03-25  11        buy      8.90
2011-03-25   2        sell    28.00
2011-03-25  99        hold
```

The log stops at `2011-03-25`. For `2011-03-26`, I want to know:
 - what stocks are still left in the portfolio
 - for what price and on what date these stocks were orginally bought

If we do this manually:
 - stock `11` is bought on `2011-03-21`, sold on `2011-03-22`, but bought again on `2011-3-25` for `8.90` and we haven't sold it since, so it is still in portfolio on `2011-03-26`
 - stock `55` is bought on `2011-03-21` and sold on `2011-03-22` so not in portfolio anymore
 - stock `99` is bought on `2011-03-21` and we have held it and never sold so it is still in portfolio on `2011-03-26` for a price of `5.15`
 - stock `1` and `2` are both bought and sold before `2011-03-26`

So the portfolio on `2011-03-26` consists of:

```
sp100_id  buy_date    buy_price
-------------------------------
11        2011-03-25  8.90
99        2011-03-21  5.15
```

My question is: with what query can the above output be returned from the table?

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77186)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.sp100_id, t1._date as buy_date, t1.price
from (select * from portfolio where action='buy')  t1
    left join (select * from portfolio where action='sell') t2 
      on t1.sp100_id=t2.sp100_id
    and t1._date<t2._date
where t2.sp100_id is null
```

Comment: This is indeed clean :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77186/24)

```
select t0.* from portfolio t0
join
(
select sp100_id,max(_date) mdate from portfolio t
   where action = 'buy'
      and 
        not exists (select sp100_id from portfolio t2
                     where t2.sp100_id=t.sp100_id
                           and t2._date>t._date
                           and t2.action='sell')
group by sp100_id
) t1 on (t0.sp100_id=t1.sp100_id) and (t0._date=t1.mdate)
```